# Translating PS2 Buzz Controller's ByteArray inputs to button presses with node-hid, socket.io and Javascript

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, arrays, hid

I'm in the process of making a HTML5 game that uses controllers that came bundled with the PlayStation 2 game **Buzz!: The Music Quiz**.

I currently have a node server running locally with node-static, nodemon and socket.io and have successfully connected the USB Buzz controllers using node-hid.

Writing bytes to the device is trivial and I can easily turn on/off each of the four controller's lights by writing a *0x00* or *0xff* to the appropriate bit.

I need help with translating the complex input reports which are in the form of a byteArray and converting these to recognisable button presses using JavaScript/jQuery. Each of the four controllers have five buttons (buzzer, blue, orange, green and yellow) and information is sent when a button is pressed and released.

Information about the input bit format can be seen here: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/

node-hid: https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What content are you currently getting in the byteArray?

Comment: In the node command prompt: `<Buffer 00 00 00 00 f0>` which I have converted to an array `var array = new Int8Array(data);`, which outputs: `[0, 0, 0, 0, -16]` in the console